# How can I conditionally colour points on a scatter plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

I am trying to draw a plot (using scatter or plot) on a set of data.
I have a `data` array which contains the values. 
I also have a `confidence` array which contains values from 0 to 1 to indicate how reliable that value is.
In my scatter plot I have to plot the values which have confidence lower than 0.5 in a different colour.

So far I have:

```
for i=1:length(data)
    if confidence(i) < 0.5
        colour(i) = 'g';
    else
        colour(i) = 'b';
    end
end

f = figure;
scatter(xvalues,data,[],colour,'x');
```

**The problem:**

I expect there to be green and blue x's but the plot shows all blue.
I have checked that there are confidence values which are definitely lower that 0.5.
I am not sure how else to specify the colours.

I am using Matlab R2013a.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply plot twice, using the `hold on` command:

```
data = rand(10,1);
confidence = rand(10,1);
xvalues = rand(10,1);

f = figure; hold on;
scatter(xvalues(confidence<0.5),data(confidence<0.5),'g');
scatter(xvalues(confidence>=0.5),data(confidence>=0.5),'b');
```

Notice that you can selectively pick out the values you want by directly selecting `xvalues(confidence<0.5)` without a for loop (try entering `confidence<0.5` in the command window to see what it does).

Also, for the future, it's very useful if your code is a self-contained MWE (minimum working example). This means also generating some data points, so other people can just copy/paste and run your code directly : ).

Comment: Thanks @lifesayko! This has solved my problem and I will bear the MWE in mind.

Answer (score 0):

When color is specified as a string it cannot be varied for the points. Your code should throw an error but fortunately it does not.

To do it the way you have it, I think lifesayko's answer is the better one. What if you wanted to show 10 different colors on the plot ? 
In that case, you would want to specify color as RGB triplets, which means `color` would be a three column matrix.

```
color = zeros(size(data));
color(confidence < 0.5,:) = [0 1 0];
color(confidence >= 0.5,:) = [0 0 1];
scatter(xvalues,data,color);
```