# How to assign color to points in graph

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

I need to plot a graph in which each point (x,y,z) has a color assigned based on its value.  How can I do this in Matlab?
I have tried:
scatter3(x, y, z, c)
but I had difficulty with color.

Consider this example:
(x_i,y_i,z_i) has value of v_i. I want the point with max value to be red and the point with min value to be blue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603566/how-can-i-conditionally-colour-points-on-a-scatter-plot-in-matlab/34603715#34603715) question. Check that one out, and if that doesn't answer you, post your code so we can actually see what is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. I am assuming that you need the color on the basis of `z`. That is why there is a second `z` in scatter3. You can replace it with another matrix on the basis of which color will be displayed.

```
s=50; %size of marker
scatter3(x, y, z, s ,z,'filled');
colormap(jet);
colorbar;
```

If you need a color variation blue-white-red . Then use this code.

```
s=50; %size of marker
scatter3(x, y, z, s ,z,'filled');
m = size(get(gcf,'colormap'),1)/2;
steps = (0:m-1)'/max(m-1,1);
cm_red_blue = [ steps steps ones(m,1);ones(m,1) flipud(steps) flipud(steps) ]; 
colormap(cm_red_blue);
colorbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use it like:

```
scatter3(x, y, z, s, c)
```

where `s` is the size of the markers.

If you use it like you did Matlab thinks that the color is a size value and most probably returns an error.